# Javascript click function for multiple Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So basically I have this little social networking site which allow comments. I've built a comment section that will slide down once a user clicks "Comment" and it slides down under the users status.

My problem is that right now, the JavaScript only works on ONE post ID, and not the rest obviously seeing you can only use an ID once. But of course if I use classes instead, All the comment sections slide down because now they're all the same class.  See below for my HTML and JavaScript.

So if someone has a better method out there, please help :)

```
$(function () {
    $(".comment-box").slideUp();

    //when "comment" is clicked, slide down the comment box. 
    if ($(".comment-box-btn").click(function () {
        $(".comment-box").slideDown();
    }));
    //when "cancel" is clicked, slide up the comment box.
    if ($(".close-comment-box").click(function () {
        $(".comment-box").slideUp()
    }));

});
```

And here's the HTML used

```
//anchor for "Comment" 
<a class="comment-box-btn" href="#"><i class="icon-comment"></i> Comment</a>


//comment box
<div class="row comment-box" style="display:none;">
<div class="col-md-12">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" method="post"> 
<textarea class="form-control animated" cols="180" id="new-comment" name="comment" placeholder="Comment.." rows="1"></textarea>

<div class="text-right" style="margin-top:20px;">
<a class="btn btn-default close-comment-box" href="#">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</a>
<button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Comment</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each comment box is adjacent to their button, you could do

**REVISED VERSION** :

```
$(function () {
    //slide up the box on page load. 
    $(".comment-box").slideUp();
    $(".comment-box-btn").each(function (i) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            $(".comment-box").eq(i).slideDown(500, function () {
                $(this).find(".close-comment-box").click(function () {
                    $(".comment-box").eq(i).slideUp()
                });
            });
        }); // click
    }); // each
});
```

see NEW **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/njLwn/1/)**

Comment: if you have multiple comment-btn instances and open them up at the same time. Closing/sliding up wud be problem?http://jsfiddle.net/ankitjc/KuRtW/3/

Comment: @ajc that works on JSfiddle but not when uploaded to my server lol

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `$(".comment-box").slideDown();` and `$(".comment-box").slideUp();` on the handlers, try using `$(this)` and the `parent()` function. If I'm not mistaken, the buttons are three levels in so it's gonna be:

```
$(function(){ 

//slide up the box on page load. 
    $(".comment-box").slideUp(); 

    //when "comment" is clicked, slide down the comment box. 
    if($( ".comment-box-btn" ).click( function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().slideDown();
    {
     //when "cancel" is clicked, slide up the comment box.
     if($( ".close-comment-box" ).click( function() {
         $(this).parent().parent().parent().slideUp()
     }));
     }}));
     });;
```

Comment: the OP doesn't want to `slideDown` the `.comment-box-btn` button ;)

Comment: yeah.. that's not going to work. That would ask `.comment-box-btn` to slide down...

Answer (score 0):

If the `close-comment-box` button is inside the `comment-box`, you can just find the parent:

```
$('.close-comment-box').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.comment-box:eq(0)').slideUp();
});
```

This way it only applies the parent `comment-box` the button belongs to, not all comment boxes.